# CNN: Is it better to train 300.000 images during 1 epoch or 300 images during 1000 epoch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, epoch, yolo

This question is related to convolutionals neural networks (especially YoloV3)

Since one epoch is one forward pass and one backward pass of all the training examples, for the model to converge properly, is it the same (in terms of precision and time to converge) to :

- train with **n*k images** during **m epochs** ?
- train with **n images** during **m*k epochs** ?

Comment: You have said "one epoch is one forward pass and one backward pass of all the training examples". So just train "all training examples each epoches".

Answer (score 0):

You will generally get a better model using n*k images on m epochs, otherwise you are prone to [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) very easily.

There are also many papers that research this area (why more data seems to always be better), e.g. [this one](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P01-1005).

I'd recommend to train on all available data (minus a test and validation set) for as long as either the model has not converged or there is no consistent downward trend in the test metric (in which case you are probably overfitting the training data).

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same.

*The number of examples you show the network defines what it will be looking for - a network with more examples will tend to be more general. If there are, for example, 1000 pictures with different dogs in it, and you only show 300/300000 pictures, the network (on average) will only recognize one specific kind of dog, and be unable to pick out common traits of all dogs.

*An epoch is basically modifying the network in a small step, and the key word here is small - taking too big steps risk overshooting our target values for the network parameters. Since we´re taking small steps, we have to take several of them to get where we want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But what I would like to know is : if I put 300.000 images of one single dog - let's say a german shepherd -, and I train during one epoch (or 300.000 iterations), will my loss function will be as low as training 300 images of this dog on 1000 epochs ? I mean, will the CNN take advantages from new images for converging or is it better for training faster to reduce number of images but make more epochs ? since overfitting is not an issue if I train to recognize only one single dog